# Does using @import in a CSS file cut down on HTTP request?

Tags: css

If I have a CSS file that is included into the page like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
```

And then that file has...

```
@import "shCore.scss";
@import "shThemeDjango.scss";
```

Does this do 1 HTTP request or 3?

Is there a benefit of importing multiple files vs linking to all of them in the main file?

(I know the ideal solution is to combine all and minify)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not using @import.  This stops the browser from downloading files in parallel as it has to parse the first css file.  Then go retrieve the import css files and import them.

[google on @import](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#AvoidCssImport)

As you mentioned combining and minifying your css is the best option.  Using a tool like [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) allows you to keep your stylesheets separate and clean but serve them combined and  minified.

Comment: Which by the way means that it does 3 HTTP requests

Comment: Great thats what I wanted to hear, I always stayed away from them because I assumed it wasn't good but I didn't have any real reasoning for it.  I notice a lot of wordpress themes do the import.  I minify and combine in my Build scripts

Answer (score 0):

This would still mean three HTTP-request, and there it most likely make the load process even slower, as Jros mention.

Instead I suggest that you minify all your CSS into one file, to make as few HTTP-requests as possible, and to decrease the amount of data that needs to be transferred.

Here's an [example](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/) of a CSS minifying tool you can use, if you don't want to do it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think, given the context of the question, there has been some misleading advice. Sure, "vanilla" CSS `@import` will make a HTTP request. But the OP seems to be using a pre-processor.

Pre-processors, such as; SASS or LESS, work by compiling down your code, often into a singular `css` file. Meaning an `@import` has already been handled and included for you. You just reference the end-point stylesheet.

So no. Knock yourself out, when using a pre-processor. It's a great way to organise your code.